# select2 shows first option instead of placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2

I have this in my .cshtml

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Attendance.Time02InId, new SelectList(Model.ClockingLocations, "Id", "Name"), new {@class = "form-control select2-allow-clear"})
```

`Model.ClockingLocations` = List of `Clock`

```
public class Clock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's my jquery on document ready

```
    var placeholder = "Select...";

    $(".select2-allow-clear").prepend("<option></option>");

    $(".select2-allow-clear").select2({
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        width: null
    });
```

However, my select list still shows the first item of my `Model.ClockingLocations` when `m.Attendance.Time02InId` has no value, instead of my placeholder.

Comment: Just use the built in method for adding the label option - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Attendance.Time02InId, new SelectList(Model.ClockingLocations, "Id", "Name"), "Select...", new {@class = "form-control select2-allow-clear"})` and remove `placeholder: placeholder,`

Comment: @StephenM, this works great for razor syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your JQuery code

```
var placeholder = "Select...";

$(".select2-allow-clear").prepend("<option></option>");

$(".select2-allow-clear").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: placeholder,
    width: null
});
```

with

```
var placeholder = "Select...";

$(".select2-allow-clear").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");

$(".select2-allow-clear").select2({
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: placeholder,
    width: null
});
```

You can also try replacing

```
$(".select2-allow-clear").prepend("<option></option>");
```

with

```
$(".select2-allow-clear").prepend("<option value=''></option>").val('');
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This sets all my dropdown list with a placeholder even when `m.Attendance.Time02InId` has a value that needs to be displayed.

Comment: In that case, I am sorry I don't know how will you get the value of m.Attendance.Time02InId in javascript code but you will have to put this prepend line under some condition so that it doesn't set the value in all cases.

Comment: @NitinGarg Changing that .prepend  <option></option> to the one with val='' definatly worked for me. Huge thanks mate!